# Trouble using a 'before_filter' method and rendering partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, render

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to understand the behavior of the `before_filter` method in a controller.

In my controller I have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize

  def show
    ...
  end
end
```

If I browse, for example, the page `http://<my_web_site>/user/1` (that loads the `users/show.html.erb` view file populated of data from the User with ID 1) the `before_filter` works as well. That is, the `authorize` method does what it must do.

*If I render the `users/show.html.erb` view file as a template for another controller (example: the PostsController) this way*

```
# This code is in the `post/show.html.erb` file
<%= render :template => "/users/show", :locals => { :user => @user } %>
```

*the `before_filter` doesn't work*. That is, the `authorize` method seams do not run.

**Why?! There is a reason for that behavior or I am wrong somewhere?**

---

**UPDATE** (after the @brad comment)

> Are you rendering that view as a
>   partial template from within the users
>   controller? If not the before_filter
>   won't apply

If it is as @brad say in his comment, **how can I make the `before_filter` to work rendering that view for another controller than UsersController?**

Comment: Not sure what you mean with this questions. Code sample?

Comment: Are you rendering that view as a partial template from within the users controller? If not the before_filter won't apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move authorize method to ApplicationController
2. Add before_filter to each controller where you want to check user authorization.

Answer (score 0):

When you render a template or a view file/partial, it is not really treated as a request on your controller, hence the filters dont apply.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should understand the routing in the Rails. When you type in the browser `http://<my_web_site>/user/1` then it goes to `route` file, after this to proper controller's action, after that controller initiate the render view. And controller has these callbacks, when some action is initiated then these callbacks should act before or after controller's action. So in your case you're calling partial template without any controller's involving

Comment: How can I involve a controller to properly render the view and make the 'before_filter' to work?

Comment: I think the initiating of these callbacks somehow embedded inside Rails, so only way to trigger the callback is put http://<my_web_site>/user/1 in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

`before_filter` applies to controller actions, not rendering actions.

One solution, then, is to abstract your authorization logic out into a helper that can be used when you're rendering your partial:

```
if authorized?
  render :partial => 'users/show'
end
```

Another solution is to implement authorization at the model level, using something like the `declarative_authorization` gem (https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization)